# How to set korean keyboard layout by hs.keycodes.setLayout()?

Tags: macos, hammerspoon

I want to change keyboard layout by using `Hammerspoon`.

To change Thai keyboard layout, this code works.

```
> hs.keycodes.setLayout("Thai")
true
```

But to change Korean keyboard, both codes doesn't work.

```
> hs.keycodes.setLayout("2-Set Korean")
false

> hs.keycodes.setLayout("Korean")
false
```

`hs.keycodes.currentLayout()` returns "2-Set Korean".

```
> hs.keycodes.currentLayout()
2-Set Korean
```

Where can I find corret keyboard layout name for each language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `setLayout()` you need to use `setMethod()` for Korean input method.

```
hs.keycodes.setMethod("2-Set Korean")
```